# alternating row color disappears after initial onload in Chrome and Firefox....works fine in IE

Tags: css

The CSS:

```
 tr.row1 { background-color: #FFFFFF; }

 tr.row2 { background-color: #E0E0FF; }
```

I am using pagination and the results show fine in IE but disappear in Chrome and Firefox when advancing forward from page 1.

Comment: We need some more code to help you.

Comment: I did a sample with alternating row color just now and it works fine for me in all browsers. Maybe we need to see some markup?

Comment: A URL would probably be most helpful

Comment: my guess is that it's malformed HTML on the 2nd page.

Comment: that site works fine for me -- did you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't answer your question, but if the alternating row colour isn't crucial, you can do this with CSS3 nth-child selector, which works with [newer versions](http://kimblim.dk/css-tests/selectors/) of all browsers:

```
tr:nth-child(even) {background: #FFFFFF}
tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #E0E0FF}
```